# Using for loops to save a matrix of data?

Tags: r, probability-density

I am trying to find the probability density functions of a wind data. Below is how I calculate the scale parameter from the mean wind speeds.

```
k<-2
for(i in 1:length(Windmean)){
      Scale[i]=as.numeric(Windmean[i]/(exp(gammaln(1+(1/k)))))
      }

> Scale
 [1] 3.913934 3.996000 4.012884 3.925220 3.856707 3.849608 3.820578 3.943110 3.945975 3.842338 3.891791
[12] 3.933083 3.993944 3.907775 3.847120 3.853263 3.917156 4.028956 3.878879 3.753880 3.969074 3.818923
[23] 3.855913 3.993075 3.985828 3.914240 3.854336 3.620460 3.848180 3.843788 3.830617 3.841890 3.879547
[34] 3.904059
```

If these are my results for scale parameter I want to use the formula below to get the wind probability `Wind_prob.` I do.

```
Scale<- cbind(3.913934,3.996000,4.012884,3.925220,3.856707,3.849608,
3.820578,3.943110,3.945975,3.842338,3.891791,3.933083,3.993944,3.907775,
3.847120,3.853263,3.917156,4.028956,3.878879,3.753880,3.969074,3.818923,
3.855913,3.993075,3.985828,3.914240,3.854336,3.620460,3.848180,3.843788,
3.830617,3.841890,3.879547,3.904059)  ##Length 34

bins<-cbind(seq(0.5,25,by=0.5)) ##Length 51
                      bins<-cbind(bins)
        shape<-k
                for(i in 1:length(bins)){
for(o in 1:length(Scale)){
                Wind_prob[i]<-(0.5*(exp(-1*(bins[i,1]/shape)^shape))*(shape/as.numeric(Scale[o]))*((bins[i,1]/as.numeric(Scale[o]))^(shape-1)))
            }
}
```

I am getting a list of 51 probability functions `(i=34)` but I should get a matrix of [51*34]. Basically, I want to get 51 probability functions for each 34 scale functions. It seems my iterations are not been saved at matrix. I tried `as.matrix`, `as.array` as well in the `wind_prob` but couldn't get it working. **Would anyone be kind to point out the changes I need to make in the code? Thanks.**

Comment: `k` is missing. `o:length(o)` is invalid. The long expression returns 1 number. You need to think more about this. Preallocate a matrix to fill and then use two indices. Right now you're not using `o`-dimension.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik `k` is given as 2, see the first half of code. yes it should be `1:length(Scale)` Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a matrix:

```
Scale <- c(3.913934,3.996000,4.012884,3.925220,3.856707,3.849608,
           3.820578,3.943110,3.945975,3.842338,3.891791,3.933083,3.993944,3.907775,
           3.847120,3.853263,3.917156,4.028956,3.878879,3.753880,3.969074,3.818923,
           3.855913,3.993075,3.985828,3.914240,3.854336,3.620460,3.848180,3.843788,
           3.830617,3.841890,3.879547,3.904059)  ##Length 34
bins <- seq(0.5, 25, by = 0.5) # length 50
shape <- 2
Wind_prob <- matrix(NA_real_, length(bins), length(Scale))
for (j in seq_along(Scale)) {
  for (i in seq_along(bins)) {
    Wind_prob[i, j]<-(0.5*(exp(-1*(bins[i]/shape)^shape))*
                        (shape/as.numeric(Scale[j]))*
                        ((bins[i]/as.numeric(Scale[j]))^(shape-1)))
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you explain why I should take `seq_along(Scale)` first and `seq_along(bins)` second in the loops? Is it because for each scale we are calculating wind_prob in each bin?

Comment: Yeap. You want to iterate on all combination of ``Scale`` and ``bins``.